# Converting multiple command prompt commands to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, batch-processing

I just started with using batch files, my whole purpose of using them is to save the time I spend running   the same commands(command line) and process (making moving folders)

Let me ask on a specific example for now:
I want to  run this two commands in a single batch file

```
cd c:dir\..\dir\bin

prompt:

:WSDL.bat -o C:\somepatch\..\dir -uri someURL.xml
```

now instead of writing this three commands  individually , I want them written on a single batch file , which would run every time the batch file is run.

I tried bunch of things ,but didn't really work  out

Comment: and what does not work?

Comment: show us some of the bunch of things that don't work.

Comment: Please, do not post code snippets in comments, as it becomes slightly unreadable. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Sorry, I won't henceforth

Comment: DOS allows you to chain commands together using `&` and `&&`  the single `&` will cause the second command to run regardless if the first command was successful.  The `&&` only runs the second command if the first command was successful.  -edit, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/single-line-with-multiple-commands-using-windows-batch-file

Comment: start `notepad.exe`, put the three lines in and save it as `myname.bat`. Just type `myname`[Enter] to execute it. Note: it has to be somewhere, where windows can find it (either in the current working directory or in a folder defined in `&PATH%`)